# Click button after scrolling in apk

Tags: java, android, appium

I am trying to scroll in walmart.com app to click the "Add to Cart" button  but am not able to scroll. Can anyone please help here.

i am using below code but it does scroll. I am using java and

```
 driver.swipe(-23, -1278, 0, 0, 3000);
```

Attaching screenshot from UIAutomator .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaTsT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot swipe by using negative coordinate input. You must use positives for this method in loop together with verification of element presence.